# How to port my code from CryptoJS to python3?

Tags: python, encryption, utf-8, cryptojs, hmacsha256

The code is already written in javascript but i have to port it to python. I tried, but not getting the expected results. Can someone help me port this code into Python.

Javascript Script

```js
const timestamp  = new Date().toISOString();
const accessKey = 'KEY'
const secretKey = 'SECRET'
const businessVerb = ''
const payload = ''
const method = 'GET'
const url = 'https://www.google.com'

const sigData = `${url}\\n${method}\\n${accessKey}\\n${businessVerb}\\n${timestamp}\\n${payload}`;
const secretKeyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretKey);
const bytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(sigData);
const signatureBytes = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(bytes, secretKeyBytes);
const signatureBase64String = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signatureBytes);
const urlEncodedSignature = encodeURIComponent(signatureBase64String); 

console.log(timestamp)
console.log(sigData)
console.log(signatureBase64String)
console.log(urlEncodedSignature)
```

output

```
2022-04-25T06:05:04.103Z
https://www.google.com\nGET\nKEY\n\n2022-04-25T06:05:04.103Z\n
gUT78wzEtYow3UF38YUDOvRNB9rOy38ZzuqQZ3t/4uc=
gUT78wzEtYow3UF38YUDOvRNB9rOy38ZzuqQZ3t%2F4uc%3D
```

python script

```py
from datetime import datetime
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import urllib.parse
import requests
import json

#timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]+'Z'
timestamp = '2022-04-25T06:05:04.103Z'
accessKey = 'KEY'
secretKey = 'SECRET'
businessVerb = ''
payload = ''
method = 'GET'
url = 'https://www.google.com'

sigData = "{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(url,method,accessKey,businessVerb,timestamp,payload)


secretKeyBytes = secretKey.encode('utf-8')
byts = sigData.encode('utf-8')
signatureBytes = hmac.new(secretKeyBytes,
                        msg = byts,
                        digestmod = hashlib.sha256).digest()
signatureBase64String=base64.b64encode(signatureBytes).decode()
urlEncodedSignature=urllib.parse.quote(signatureBase64String)

print(timestamp)
print(sigData)
print(signatureBase64String)
print(urlEncodedSignature)
```

output

```
2022-04-25T06:05:04.103Z
https://www.google.com\nGET\nKEY\n\n2022-04-25T06:05:04.103Z\n
WqzaJF8csz5SHB4LMzeKX/sSB1TeNmId3y41nR2HT30=
WqzaJF8csz5SHB4LMzeKX/sSB1TeNmId3y41nR2HT30%3D
```

**Note: I'm using the same timestamp as in js code to get the same results in the python code**

Comment: In the Python code you use `\n` as separator regarding `sigData`, in the JavaScript code `\\n`. Additionally, in the Python code you should apply `quote_plus()` if you want to encode also `/` and `+` as in the JavaScript code.

Comment: helpful. But the problem still exist in the encoding functions used in python. are they the right functions to use?

Comment: For me, both codes (with the mentioned changes) return the *same* HMAC (as long as the same timestamp is used). I.e. I cannot reproduce the problem. Check again and post the results of your updated codes for an identical timestamp.